# What statistical test should I run with one group that I pretest, implement the intervention, and posttest?

Tags: t-test

I am administering a pretest, implementing an intervention, and then administering the post-test because I'd like to see if the scores improve due to the intervention.

Comment: If the subjects are the same pre and post test, a paired test seems reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

[Wilcoxon signed-rank test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test) (which is a paired non-parametric test) if the data is not likely to be normally distributed and a [paired (parametric) t-test](http://www.statstutor.ac.uk/resources/uploaded/paired-t-test.pdf) if the data is reasonably normal.